# Solve the integral $\int\frac{1}{4x^2 + 9} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Im a newish calc 1 student and i have been trying to solve the integral:

$$\int\dfrac{1}{4x^2 + 9} dx $$

I was able to solve the integral

$\int\frac{1}{x^2 + 1} = \arctan(x) + C$, by doing the method of $x = \tan(u)$  but with the factor of $4$ in the $x^2$ term and +$9$ I'm unsure how to go about solving this, when I put it into wolfram alpha it spits out

$$\frac{1}{6} \arctan\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right) + C$$

But I'm unsure how its came to this answer and cant find any explanations online. I'm not as interested in the actual answer to this specific question as I am how the difference in the terms leads to the different answer

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $4x^2 + 9 = 4\left( x^2 + \frac{9}{4} \right).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a well known generalized result,

$$\boxed{\int \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{a}arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+c}$$

For your case, factor out 4 and proceed as follows;

$$I=\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{1}{x^2+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}\,dx$$

Compare and put, $a=\frac{3}{2}$,

> $$I=\frac{1}{6}arctan\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)+c$$

Comment: Could the downvoter please suggest any required changes?

Comment: Imo nothing's wrong here...I did +1

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Thanks a lot but it leaves me confused of where the mistake is....

Answer (score 8):

You have an antiderivative for $1/(x^2+1).$  So if you can change your integrand into that form, you'll have the problem solved.  So there are two changes to make.  You need to change the $9$ into a $1$ and the $4$ into a $1$.

So step one is to factor $1/9$ clear out of the integral:

$$\frac{1}{9} \int \frac{1}{\frac{4}{9}x^2+1}\,dx.$$

Then notice that $\frac{4}{9}x^2 = \left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)^2$, so substitute $u = \frac{2x}{3}.$

These steps will be the same for similar integrals.  If the quadratic expression has a linear term then first complete the square, then proceed as above.

Comment: I like this answer because it explains how to get from where the student is to where they know what to do.

Comment: The "substitute u = 2x/3" felt like it came out of nowhere in the above answer but this explanation helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $u=\frac{2x}{3}$ to get $dx=\frac32du$ Now rewrite the integral as $$\int\frac{3}{2(9u^2+9)}du$$
I hope you can continue after this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all take 4 common from the denominator and then substitute x=(3tan(y))/2. Then you will sec²y in the numerator and denominator both and then you have to cancel the term sec²y in both numerator and denominator.The final answer will be 1/6 (arctan(2x/3))+C.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).